# Does Spanish have an equivalent to "beep beep!"?

Tags: vocabulario

Kind of an odd question, but I know in English there are times when you want to make your way through a crowd, or some such situation, and you might say "beep beep!", gently, to clear a path.  Of course one could say "perdona", "disculpa", or something similar, but there are times when situations call for the immediacy and directness of "beep beep!" -- to me "perdona" is best when speaking to one person, whereas "beep beep" is more of an announcement in general. I'm sure one can imagine an appropriate circumstance where it's not rude.   I assume there is no real equivalent, but have always been curious.

Comment: I doubt I would say beep beep to get through a crowd. Beep Beep is The Road Runner cartoon sound. I've seen bip bip but a single beep is un pitido.

Comment: https://hmong.es/wiki/Beep,_beep_(sound)

Comment: @Lambie I don't know if in English someone uses "beep, beep" imitating the Road Runner, but since I was little (a long time ago ) in Colombia we say «pi, pi» imitating a car horn. My understanding is that we do not sound like the Road Runner but the Road Runner sounds like a car horn. I remember sometimes Wile E. Coyote will hear the beep, turned around to catch his meal and instead found himself face to face with a truck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Que tal? "bip bip" es "pip-pip","pi-pi" ó "pipi". "p"  y "b" son sonidos bilabiales y en algunas palabras son incluso intercambiables.

En España, al menos en el sur, también decimos "pip-pip", "pi-pi" ó "pipi", depende,  sonido onomatopéyico que ilustra el sonido del "pipi", "pito" ó claxon de un vehículo con objeto de abrirnos paso en imitación a estos cuando precisan pasar y llamar la atención indicando "cuidado y atención". De pequeño lo utilizábamos mucho para atravesar la multitud, es algo más de niños. De adulto es verdad que se utilizan otras expresiones como *por favor, me permite, gracias-gracias, paso-paso ó voy-voy*... aunque yo lo sigo escuchando en ciertos momentos en tumultos, como cuando la gente se se aglomera en Semana Santa ante una procesión.

Espero haber ayudado. Saludos

Diego M.

Answer (score 4):

I think it depends on the country. I only know the case of Argentina and Colombia where people say: "pi, pi" (pee pee) which is the equivalent to "beep beep".

In Spain they usually say "paso, paso", sound reduction of "abran paso" (make way).

Comment: In Colombia we also say «pi, pi». I hope you don't mind I edited to add that. :)